# Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста исправить задание. Условие и код прикрепил внизу.(В консоли выводится адрес массива, а не сам массив)

Tags: c++, массивы

```
int main()
{
#pragma region Ukranian
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ukrainian");
#pragma endregion
    const int size = 9;
    float a[size] = { 0.f };
    int i = 0;
    float y = -5.5f;
    float x = -1.8f;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) < 1)
            a[i] = x * y;
        else
            a[i] = sqrt(fabs(x * y));
        x += 0.2f;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << " A = " << a[size] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    
}
```

[image: Само задание]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << " A = " << a[i] << endl;
}
```

думаю ты уже и сам уже разобрался

Comment: ааа...
Невнимательный, спасибо за ваш ответ